# Problem with GDAL_WMS QGIS connecting to an ArcGIS Server?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, gdal, wms

I've been working, trying to get QGIS (*v2.0 32bit*) to connect to an ArcGIS Server service using the GDAL_WMS xml file. This is the service I'm trying to connect to:

http://geonb.snb.ca/ArcGIS/rest/services/GeoNB_Basemap_Imagery/MapServer/?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

This is the xml file I currently have:

```
<GDAL_WMS>
   <Service name="TMS">
        <Version>1.1.1</Version>
      <ServerUrl>http://geonb.snb.ca/ArcGIS/rest/services/GeoNB_Basemap_Imagery/MapServer/tile/${z}/${y}/${x}.jpg</ServerUrl>
        <Layers>Bathurst_ortho_final_graphic,SDEDO.FTON_ORTHOS_Clip2,MiramichiOrthos,SDEDO.snbortho,Year of Photography</Layers>
        <ImageFormat>image/jpeg</ImageFormat>
   </Service>
   <DataWindow>
        <UpperLeftX>2282341.95</UpperLeftX>
        <UpperLeftY>7698181.3</UpperLeftY>
        <LowerRightX>2737347.05</LowerRightX>
        <LowerRightY>7252058.7</LowerRightY>
        <TileLevel>13</TileLevel>
        <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
        <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
        <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
    </DataWindow>
    <Projection>EPSG:2953</Projection>
    <BlockSizeX>512</BlockSizeX>
    <BlockSizeY>512</BlockSizeY>
    <BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
    <MaxConnections>10</MaxConnections>
    <Cache />
</GDAL_WMS>
```

And this is what I get:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIZyR.png]

This is not a WMS issue. The service doesn't support WMS connections and that's the reason for using the XML with GDAL. GDAL then creates a "WMS" like service on top of the images using the XML. It basically fetches images and puts them in the right spot. What I think is happening is it misinterpreting what tiles to fetch and how to stretch them. (Maybe)

Here's an example of a tile fetched directly from the service:
http://geonb.snb.ca/ArcGIS/rest/services/GeoNB_Basemap_Imagery/MapServer/tile/0/64/64.jpg
[http://geonb.snb.ca/ArcGIS/rest/services/GeoNB_Basemap_Imagery/MapServer/tile/0/64/64.jpg http://geonb.snb.ca/ArcGIS/rest/services/GeoNB_Basemap_Imagery/MapServer/tile/0/64/64.jpg](http://geonb.snb.ca/ArcGIS/rest/services/GeoNB_Basemap_Imagery/MapServer/tile/0/64/64.jpg)

This all works so there's something wrong with my XML. The documentation for the XML is here(www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html), but it's not very descriptive. The specific section that relates to what I want to accomplish is the TMS service.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are running QGIS 64bit?

Comment: QGIS 2.0 32bit (*I've expanded my question*)

Comment: The problem may be related to this: Level 0 of the service has 4 tiles, not a single one that the utility might be expecting. Maybe somebody who has more knowledge of GDAL would know.

Comment: I have the save problem and i think it is due to different SRS projection (with EPSG:4326, EPSG:3857 it works). I tried this http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms_arcgis_mapserver_tms.xml with QGIS and it worked, but no successful attempts to adapt it to local arcgis services with EPSG:3346 - same random points image.

Answer (score 3):

I  get the same result

But I don't see WMS in the Supported Interfaces of the service:

[image]

In contrast, An ArcGIS Server service with WMS Supported Interfaces work without problem

[image]

So I suppose that's the reason (no WMS service).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but that's why I'm using the XML with GDAL because the site doesn't support WMS. If it did I'd use WMS. The XML acts as a wrapper to the Tile Service. I've expanded my question to better explain my problem. Thanks again.